# Spring / Thymeleaf: Property or field cannot be found on null, but still rendering

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc, thymeleaf

I have a Spring / Thymeleaf app that

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 0): Property or field 'projectName' cannot be found on null
```

However, the page looks normal. All variables are rendering with data. I'm just concerned that an exception is being thrown every request.

Here is the controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/download")
public class AppDownloaderController {

    @Autowired
    InstallLinkJoinedService installLinkJoinedService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/link/{installLink}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getInstallLink(Model model, @PathVariable("installLink") String installLink) {
        InstallLinkJoined installLinkJoined = installLinkJoinedService.getInstallLinkWithID(installLink);
        if (installLinkJoined != null) {
            model.addAttribute("install", installLinkJoined);
        }
        return "download";
    }
}
```

A snippet of the html in question:

```
<h3 class="achievement-heading text-primary" th:text="${install.projectName}"></h3>
```

The field is part of the InstallLinkJoined object:

```
@Column(nullable = false)
private String projectName;
```

And I have getters and setters for all fields.

If I comment out the offending line, I simply get an exception at the next variable.

And, as mentioned, all the data in the page is showing up so obviously the model object is not null...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding `install` attribute by checking null,if it's null then nothing will be initialized & then you are taking that in jsp `th:text="${install.projectName}"`,so it's saying **`cannot be found on null`**.

So change to

```
InstallLinkJoined installLinkJoined = installLinkJoinedService.getInstallLinkWithID(installLink);
if (installLinkJoined != null) {
    model.addAttribute("install", installLinkJoined);
} else {
    model.addAttribute("install", new InstallLinkJoined());
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!