# SpelEvaluationException:Property or field 'username' cannot be found on null

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

my project is based on springboot and bootstrap, i'm going to keep the username 
 when a person login in with error,but i don't want to use the ajax.so i used the thymeleaf to show the message from model. here is my project entrance:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfigure extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
    modelMap.addAttribute("user", new User());
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("pages/admin3/login_soft");
    registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    super.addViewControllers(registry);
    String os = System.getProperty("os.name");
    if(os.toLowerCase().startsWith("win")){
        Browse("http://localhost:8085");
    }

}
```

and this is my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("user")
public class UserController extends BaseController {

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView login(@ModelAttribute User user) {
    User byUsernameOrEmail = 
    userRepository.findUserByUsernameOrEmail(user.getUsername(), 
    user.getUsername());

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.addObject("user", user);
    if (CommonUtils.isEmpty(byUsernameOrEmail)) {
        mv.addObject("message", ExceptionMsg.LoginNameNotExist.getMsg());
        mv.setViewName("redirect:/");
        return mv;
    } else if (!PasswordUtils.getMD5(user.getPassword() + 
            byUsernameOrEmail.getSalt())
            .equals(byUsernameOrEmail.getPassword())) {
     mv.addObject("message",ExceptionMsg.LoginNameOrPassWordError.getMsg());
        mv.setViewName("redirect:/");
        return mv;
    }

    mv.setViewName("pages/admin3/login_soft");

    return mv;
}
```

and this  is my html :

```
 <form class="login-form"  th:action="@{/user/login}" th:object="${user}"  method="post" >

                <h3 class="form-title">登录</h3>
                <div class="alert alert-danger"  th:if="${#httpServletRequest.getParameter('message')}">
                    <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
                    <span th:text="${#httpServletRequest.getParameter('message')}"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <!--ie8, ie9 does not support html5 placeholder, so we just show field title for that request.getCookies()-->
                    <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Username</label>
                    <div class="input-icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        <input class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="用户名|邮箱"
                               name="username"  th:value="${user.username}"  />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Password</label>
                    <div class="input-icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                        <input class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" type="password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="密码" name="password"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"/> 记住密码 </label>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn blue pull-right">
                    登录 <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>

        </form>
```

when i started the project ,it showed that :

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 0): Property or field 'username' cannot be found on null
            at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:220) ~[spring-expression-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:94) ~[spring-expression-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:46) ~[spring-expression-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:375) ~[spring-expression-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88) ~[spring-expression-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:120) ~[spring-expression-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:267) ~[spring-expression-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.spring4.expression.SpelVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SpelVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:139) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariable(VariableExpression.java:154) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:59) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:103) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:133) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:120) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.attr.AbstractStandardSingleAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.getTargetAttributeValue(AbstractStandardSingleAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.java:67) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringValueAttrProcessor.getTargetAttributeValue(SpringValueAttrProcessor.java:71) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractSingleAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.getModifiedAttributeValues(AbstractSingleAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.java:59) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.processAttribute(AbstractAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.java:62) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttrProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttrProcessor.java:87) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.processor.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:212) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.applyNextProcessor(Node.java:1017) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:972) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.dom.Document.process(Document.java:93) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1155) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1257) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

i've searched many other questions,they suggested that put the [user] to the model,howerver i've did that ,why did it still show this error?   [releated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39630576/spring-thymeleaf-property-or-field-cannot-be-found-on-null-but-still-renderi)

Answer (score 0):

You're using *user* also in the *th:object* `th:object="${user}"`

Try renaming the user object by something else and also make sure that the object that you're passing to the model is populated properly.

Something like `mv.addObject("userDetails", user);` and then in your html:

```
<input class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="用户名|邮箱" name="username" th:value="${userDetails.username}"/>
```